# Powershell versioning file on partition

Tags: powershell, security, settings, system

How can i enable system properties - Advanced system settings - system security - protection settings. In protection settings in available drives column enable versioning for disc for non system partition using Win32 class.

```
$enablesecurity = get-wmiobject win32_(i dont know) -enableallprivilages
$enablesecurity.(i dont know) = $true;
$enablesecurity.Put();
```

Comment: Can you please be more explicit into the nature of your issue?

Comment: How can i enable security setting on partition D:\ using powershell?

Comment: Please [edit] your question, there's no need for a screenshot.  Show us what you've written so far, and be clear about what "security setting" you're trying to change/fix.

Comment: I dont know how can i better explain. I need enable versioning on workstations on non system partition. I dont know win32_class which can i use.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of different security settings available in Windows, can you give us the official name of the setting you are trying to set?  or at least tell us what it's called in the GUI?

Comment: Also, what does enabling security settings have to do with versioning a file?

Comment: system properties - Advanced system settings - system security - protection settings. In protection settings in available drives column enable versioning for disc

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for enabling System Restore, there is [SystemRestore class in the root/default namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378951(v=vs.85).aspx). It sounds like you want the [Enable method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378858(v=vs.85).aspx) from that class.

Comment: Hmm in this class i can do only restore point? I need file versioning for nonsystem partition. Is it the same?

Comment: System Properties - Advanced System Settings - System Security - Protection Settings are settings for System Restore or (System Protection in Windows 10). If you are looking for Volume Shadow Copy, that would be Win32_ShadowCopy in Root\CIMV2

Answer (score 0):

Answer form my question is enable-computerrestore -drive "C:\", "D:\".

Comment: Your question specifically asked for the WMI class/methods rather than the PowerShell cmdlet...

Comment: Yes. But i dont know that this is powershell cmdlet, sory. I thought than i must do this using wmi.